# Setting QScrollArea background to transparent makes contents disappear and changes scroll bar looks

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

So a simple scroll area with many buttons would look like this:

[image]

with the following code:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QScrollArea, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton

class TestWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        scroll = QScrollArea()
        # scroll.setStyleSheet('background: transparent')
        widget = QWidget(self)
        widget.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())
        for i in range(10):
            widget.layout().addWidget(QPushButton())
        scroll.setWidget(widget)

        self.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())
        self.layout().addWidget(scroll)

        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = TestWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

but if I use `scroll.setStyleSheet('background: transparent')` to set the background of the scroll area to transparent, it makes the buttons disappear and changes how the scroll bar looks:

[image]

Apparently I am doing something wrong. Can you please help me spot my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that I just have to change the background of the scroll area specifically using `scroll.setStyleSheet('QScrollArea {background: transparent;}')`

Comment: Remember that Qt stylesheets always propagate to children, like their original counterpart (they are "cascading") so [selectors](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types) are mandatory for container widgets, otherwise all properties are used on all children.